# Add attribute under currency setup on configuration page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom, system-config

I have successfully built a custom module to integrate an additional section on configuration page "Hide price option" with help of this tutorial [create custom module](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-back-end-configuration-in-magento--cms-23265)

Now I want to have this form under Currency setup configuration page if possible otherwise after currency setup page under general config page.

I tried with changing namespace but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `system.xml` with this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <currency>
            <groups>
                <section_one translate="label">
                    <label>Section One</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                
                    <fields>
                        <custom_field_one>
                            <label>Custom Text Field</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Example of text field.</comment>                   
                        </custom_field_one>
                    </fields>
                </section_one>

                <!-- ADD OTHER BLOCKS HERE -->

            </groups>                
        </currency>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Like this:

[image]